# how to show message success in register form page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, messagebox

How to show message success in WordPress. I use WooCommerce template plugin. here's my CSS code:

```
.alert.success {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.6s;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: hide;
}
```

This is my form-handler:

```
wp_safe_redirect( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) );
exit;
```

My function.php:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'maxlian_cw_register_redirect');
    function maxlian_cw_register_redirect( $redirect ) {
        $redirect = get_site_url().'/my-account';
        return $redirect;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create and echo a php variable in page where you want to show the alert and after successfully query is run set the variable to the html output that you want to show and it will show on your website